# How to abort ajax query in android-query?

Tags: java, android, ajax, json, android-query

I'm trying to implement search autocompletion with android-query library

I have callback instance in my activity:

Callback:

```
class SearchCompleteCallback extends AjaxCallback<ItemSearchResult> {
    public void callback(String url, ItemSearchResult searchResult, AjaxStatus status) {
            Log.d("SCB", String.format("Url:%s\n  Msg: %s\n  Code: %s\n  Error: %s",
                                       url,
                                       status.getMessage(),
                                       status.getCode(),
                                       status.getError()));
            if (searchResult != null) {
                Log.d("SCB", String.format("Status: %s\n  Val: %s",
                                           searchResult.getStatus(),
                                           searchResult.getInnGroup().getItems()));
                
                updateSearchResult(searchResult);
            }
            else {
                Log.w("SCB", "Ajax failed");
                
            }
    }
}
```

Search routine, that called on text change:

```
private void doSearch(String query) {
    ppApi.getSearchResult(query, searchCompleteListener);
}
```

and

#### APIClass

```
public class PPServerApi {
    private AQuery aq;
    private GsonTransformer transformer;
    
    private static class GsonTransformer implements Transformer{
        public <T> T transform(String url, Class<T> type, String encoding, byte[] data, AjaxStatus status) {
            Gson g = new Gson();
            return g.fromJson(new String(data), type);
        }
    }
    
    public PPServerApi(AQuery newAq){
        aq = newAq;
        transformer = new GsonTransformer();
        AQUtility.setDebug(true);
        AjaxCallback.setTransformer(transformer);
    }

    public void getSearchResult(String itemName, AjaxCallback<ItemSearchResult> cb){
            String url = "http://my.api.server/search?q=" + itemName;
            aq.ajax(url, ItemSearchResult.class, cb.header("content-type", "application/json"));
        }
}
```

So, the question is how to abort old queries before sending new one ?
(I don't need result of old queries if text in search field changed)

I've tried to call searchCompleteListener.abort() in doSearch(), but it causes exception in next going query:

```
08-09 20:59:10.551: W/AQuery(6854): get:http://my.api.server/search?q=abc
08-09 20:59:10.551: W/AQuery(6854): creating http client
08-09 20:59:10.561: W/AQuery(6854): java.io.IOException: Aborted
08-09 20:59:10.561: W/AQuery(6854):     at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.httpDo(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:1569)
...
```

so, i can't perform even single query in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of making android-query cancel an AJAX request once it has been started.
You'll have to use another library, sorry.

What you **can** do is to check if the request has become obsolete when it finishes.

You could do that by checking if the URL matches the latest URL you requested for

```
if (searchResult != null && url.equals(latestRequestUrl)) {
```

(note, you'd have to let getSearchResult return the URL)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library instead. Using *droidQuery*, you can cancel all Ajax tasks using the call:

```
$.ajaxKillAll();
```

You can also perform your request with this:

```
$.ajax(new AjaxOptions().url(url).header("content-type", "application/json").type("json").dataType("GET").dataType("json").success(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) params[0];
        //TODO handle json
    }
}).error(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        AjaxError error = (AjaxError) params[0];
        Log.e("Ajax", "Error " + error.status + ": " + error.reason);
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can abort any aquery processing using this.

```
private AjaxCallback<String> ajaxCallback = new AjaxCallback<String>(){
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, String object, AjaxStatus status) {
               //do your processing with server response
                   processInformation(result);
        };
    };
   //on our previous code
   query.ajax(remoteUrl,String.class,ajaxCallback);

   public void cancelAquery(){
      //this statement does cancel the request i.e. we won't receive any information on callback method
     //ajaxCallback.async(null);  

     ajaxCallback.abort();
}
```

For more info, you can see this link https://laaptu.wordpress.com/tag/android-cancelling-aquery/

Answer (score -2):

just call aq.ajaxCancel() for more details refer to the API docs

http://android-query.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/androidquery/AbstractAQuery.html#ajaxCancel()

Comment: Documentation is obsolete. Look at https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery/blob/master/src/com/androidquery/AbstractAQuery.java#L2226 , it says "Stop all ajax activities. Should only be called when app exits."